# javascript to open a firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I try to open a new tab of Firefox extension (URL starts like `chrome://xxx/content`) in a web page.

I have tried `window.open().location='chrome://xxx/content';`, but I always got a new tab like `http://chrome://xxx/content`.

So the question is whether there is a solution to open the Firefox extension in web-page JavaScript.

If the answer is yes, how to realize it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is "no". A web page is not allowed to open browser/extension user interface elements, for security reasons.

Now the web page could notify the extension that a particular extension page needs opening: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Interaction_between_privileged_and_non-privileged_pages. But given that your question doesn't provide any details on what you are trying to achieve it isn't clear whether this is a viable approach for you.